# stuck while inserting the data into core data using plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, plist

I have one entity named "Categories" in core data which have 3 attributes.

> 1. parent_id
> 2. category_id
> 3. category_name

now in CategoriesFile.plist  under root dictionary I have created 3 arrays named

> 1. parent_id
> 2. category_id
> 3. category_name

and I have filled appropriated data in these arrays.

now I have written following code to insert the data

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CategoriesFile.plist"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
        {
            // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CategoriesFile" ofType:@"plist"];
        }

        // read property list into memory as an NSData object
        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;

        // convert static property list into dictionary object
        NSDictionary *thisGardenDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *plistDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
        if (!plistDictionary)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        }

        [plistDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
            NSManagedObject *manObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:context];

            [manObj setValue:[thisGardenDictionary objectForKey:@"category_id"]  forKey:@"category_id"];
        [manObj setValue:[thisGardenDictionary objectForKey:@"parent_id"] forKey:@"parent_id"];
        [manObj setValue:[thisGardenDictionary objectForKey:@"category_name"] forKey:@"category_name"];


             }];
 NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

but I get blank result.

can someone say what I am missing?

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being obviously wrong-- time to run through this with a debugger, to verify that `plistDictionary`, `context`, and `manObj` all look like what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

set the properties of your `NSManagedObject` 
e.g

```
[manObj setName:@"Name"];
```

etc..
and then save the context to store values in the CoreData db.

```
if (![context save:&error]) {
   NSLog(@"Unresolved error : %@", [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: where are you saving the context?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (I trust you verified that the plist is read correctly):

```
NSDictionary *allArrays = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
for (int i = 0; i < [[allArrays objectForKey:@"parent_id"] count]; i++) {
   NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription 
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" 
             inManagedObjectContext:context];
    for (NSString *s in @[@"parent_id", @"category_id", @"category_name"]) {
      [object setValue:[[allArrays objectForKey:s] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:s];
    }
}
// save
```

However, let me remark that this is a very awkward way to organize your data. Much better would be an array of dictionaries. In your setup, if all arrays do not have the same number of elements, the results will be catastrophic.